# Strange Behavior of oracle query

Tags: oracle

I am not an oracle expert. I faced a very strange problem but do not know why this occur.
My query is

```
SELECT hc.id, hc.owner_name, hc.national_id, hc.phone_no, hc.location, hc.status, hc.expiry_status, od.office_title AS issuer, hc.create_date, hc.email, hc.LATTITUDE, hc.LONGITUDE, hc.HASAD_NO, hc.NUMBERATION, hc.BREEDING_TYPE, hc.PROGENY, hc.office_id, hc.issuer_id, hc.expiry_status, hc.status FROM health_cards hc 
                    LEFT JOIN office_details od ON od.office_id = hc.issuer_id AND od.lang = :lang 
                    WHERE hc.id = :search_data_num OR hc.national_id = :search_data_num or hc.phone_no = :search_data_num OR hc.owner_name LIKE :search_data ORDER BY hc.create_date DESC, hc.id desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

When i m running this query i m getting following error

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"
```

But if i remove OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY from my query it work perfectly.

I want to know the reason why this query not working with offset statement.

Comment: Which Oracle version?

Comment: Can you add the table structures????

Answer (score 2):

You have repeated column `hc.status.`

```
`select 1 as "A" as "A"  from dual` - execute OK; 

`select * from (select 1 as "A" 
                    , 2 as "A" 
                 from dual);` - ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

If you and offset, oracle probably does something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You have the column `hc.expiry_status` twice in your select list.

The problem is that we allow this in a select list, but not within an inline view. When you add the row limiting clause, Oracle transforms the query and the transformation uses an inline view. There is a bug, 13687511 which is marked as fixed. 
Meanwhile, the workaround is to either not select it twice, or alias the column(s).